# How do I get my nightly Haskell package into Stackage LTS?

Tags: haskell, hackage, stackage, lts

Though the latest version of [my package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma) is appearing as expected in Stackage Nightly, it is [not appearing in LTS](https://www.stackage.org/package/crypto-enigma/snapshots), and instead an older version is appearing there. How do I get the latest version to appear in LTS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason an older version of your package is in LTS is explained here:

> We should not include a major version bump of a package between LTS-X.Y and LTS-X.(Y+1)

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stackage/blob/master/MAINTAINERS.md#lts-package-guarantees-and-exceptions

The version of your package in the latest LTS is 0.0.3.1, but the latest version is 0.1.1.4. The jump from 0.0.* to 0.1.* is considered a "major version bump" according to the Haskell Package Versioning Policy (PVP).

LTS 13 will be released soon, and will pick up most major version bumps such as this.